# could one ruby on rails application use two sqlite3 database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, sqlite

in my config/database.yml file

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/production.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

otherdb:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: /c/Users/dsun/Documents/apeers/db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 10000
```

and in my model, I call the new database via:`establish_connection :otherdb`

but this returns an error,`database configuration does not specify adapter`

so is it the problem that sqlite3 can not use 2 db in one time?

if so, how can I fix this.

Comment: Have a look at this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10360705/how-to-use-multiple-databases-in-a-rails-app-using-the-database-yml

Comment: What's the underlying reason that you are trying to find a solution for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course, but in each model you should define wich database to use.
You can use method establish_connection to define which database should use current model.
More here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html. But I can recommend to create several base active record classes to define the database name in each, and then just inherit your model classes from them.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have fixed this problem~ the original route is under my app's route, so I use this "../" to go back outside my app, and find the external db. I create a parent model for external db let my models to inherit as you recommended, it's working now!